# ID names should have the same number of characters in it. How do I filter for data without the appropriate number of characters than delete that data?

Tags: r, filter, character, data-cleaning

I have a dataset where id names are all suppose to have 16 characters in it. How do I filter out all of the data that does not have exactly 16 characters so I can delete it from my dataset. I am working in R Studio.

I've tried both of these in attempt to get r to retrieve data that did not have exactly 16 characters in it but it did not work. I'm new to R so I'm still figuring it out.

```
length(all_trips$ride_id != 16)
```

```
length(nchar(all_trips$ride_id !=16))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting closer and you are on the right track with `nchar()`.

I assume you have a data frame `all_trips` with a character column `ride_id`.

Your first attempt:

```
length(all_trips$ride_id != 16)
```

translates as "find all the values of ride_id that are not equal to 16, then find the length of the vector containing those values". This probably returns a single number - not what we want.

Your second attempt:

```
length(nchar(all_trips$ride_id !=16))
```

translates as "find all the values of ride_id that are not equal to 16, then count the characters in those values, then find the length of the vector containing the values". Again - not what we want.

What you want to do is:

"retain only the subset of all_trips where ride_id contains 16 characters"

Which you can do like this:

```
all_trips_filtered <- all_trips[nchar(all_trips$ride_id) == 16, ]
```

Or another way using `subset`, where you can just specify the column name:

```
all_trips_filtered <- subset(all_trips, nchar(ride_id) == 16)
```

See `?Extract` or `?subset` for more help.

Comment: Thank you!!! I'm really happy you gave me the reasons why I was incorrect as well. It's greatly appreciated.